# How do I export Google Script form data to Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, webforms, google-apps

I have built a very simple form in google scripts. The file upload feature is functional: it uploads a file to my google drive. I cannot figure out how to grab the form information (Name, Organization, Content Type), save it into a spreadsheet, and upload that to my google drive.

How do I upload the form data (text fields) to my drive?

!!UPDATE 7/19!!
Code updated with Spreadsheet App code. and improved HTML. CSS not included as I don't think it's relevant to this issue.

!!UPDATE 7/20!!
Code is working. Updated to reflect full functionality. Thanks to Sandy for the assistance.

**form.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="main">
 <div class="form">
  <form id='myForm'>
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Information Submission Form</h1>
        <h2>Center For Alternative Fuels</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
         <input id='name' type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name" class="full item" spellcheck="false">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input id='email' type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="full item" spellcheck="false">
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row indent item">
      <input id='organization' type="text" name="organization" placeholder="Organization" class="full" spellcheck="false">
     </div>

     <div class="row indent item">
       <textarea id='type' name="type" class="full" placeholder="What are you submitting? (Presentation, Educational Content,...)" rows='2'></textarea>
     </div>

     <div id='success'>
     </div>


     <div class="row indent item">
       <textarea id='info' name="info" class="full" placeholder="Describe the content you are submitting" rows='8'></textarea>
     </div>


     <input type="file" name="myFile">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" 
       onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
            .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
            return false;" style="margin-top: 20px">
  </form>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
 function fileUploaded(status) {
     document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
 }
</script>
```

**server.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

var url;

function uploadToSheet(form){

 var fullName, emailAdd, organization, fileType, fileInfo;

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("INSERT SHEET ID HERE");

 var dataArray = [];

 fullName = form.name;
 emailAdd = form.email;
 organization = form.organization;
 fileType = form.type;
 fileInfo = form.info;

 dataArray.push(fullName);
 dataArray.push(emailAdd);
 dataArray.push(organization);
 dataArray.push(fileType);
 dataArray.push(fileInfo);

 ss.appendRow('dataArray');

}

function uploadFiles(form) {

try {

  var dropbox = "Form Files";
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} 
else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

  var blob = form.myFile;    
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
  file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
  url=file.getUrl();

  return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();
} 

catch (error) {
  return error.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: The form data (text fields) could be put into a text file, and the text file saved to your Google Drive.  Or each set of form data could be saved to a row in a spreadsheet.  Or do you want the data to be attached to and saved with the uploaded file as metadata?

Comment: I would like the data to be saved in a spreadsheet...I thought I included that detail in the original post :) thanks!

Comment: You'll need to use the `SpreadsheetApp` service.  I don't think that the `doPost()` function is being triggered, and you don't need it.  You should check for data getting passed with `Logger.log()` statements.  `Logger.log('the name: ' + form.myName)`  You'll probably want to use `appendRow()`  [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: thanks Sandy. i'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code might look something like this:

```
var dataArray,org,ss,userName;

ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet_File_ID");
dataArray = [];

userName = form.myName;
org = form.myOrganization;

dataArray.push(userName);
dataArray.push(org);

ss.appendRow(dataArray);
```

Comment: check out my updated code. i'm receiving a "TypeError: Cannot call method "appendRow" of null."

Comment: The spreadsheet object is null.  You are trying to get the active spreadsheet, but it's probably not open.  You may need to open the spreadsheet by ID.

Comment: any insight as to what function i should use to open the spreadsheet?

Comment: Take a look at this documentation:  [Link to Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)